# command line closes too fast inside python using ffmpeg

Tags: python, command-line, ffmpeg

I am using python to create a Macro Module inside MevisLab environment. I wanted to use ffmpeg in command prompt inside Python. The Problem is the command prompt closes too fast that i couldnt read while executing ffmpeg.

My code

```
  t = 'ffmpeg -r'+str(ctx.field("FrameRate").value)+'-f image2 -pix_fmt yuv44p -s 1920x1080 -i'+path+'%0d.png -vodec libx264 -crf 15'+path+'.mp4'

os.system(t)
```

Comment: What do you want? To see the text output from `ffmpeg`?

Comment: I wanted to create H264 video from Images i store in a file, which i set using MevisLab Environment. I wanted to execute FFMPEG command line inside the Python script. But the problem is the command line closes too fast before i could actually read the error. I am getting the parameters from the user and saving it as a string and invoke the command line with the user given parameters

Comment: **ctx.field("FrameRate").value** is the frame rate given by the user i converted it into str to use in the command line environment inside python. The same way i got the inputs for the file name and other parameters  `path = os.path.basename(ctx.field("FileName").value)`

Comment: Don't use `os.system` for that kind of complex command lines (second-guessing the shell is difficult and unsafe). You're better off using the `subprocess` module with `shell=False`.

Comment: I did see in many forums people suggesting Sub Process instead. I feel its bit more complicated. Couldnt clearly understand how to get the same command line as mentioned above using **subprocess...** It would be great help if someone could suggest a way me being a beginner in this context

Comment: Unrelated to your question: `yuv44p` is a typo. I'm not sure what you wanted with that. `-vodec` is a typo too; use `-vcodec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to redirect stdout/stderr to file and read it later:

```
t = 'ffmpeg -r'+str(ctx.field("FrameRate").value)+'-f image2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -i'+path+'%0d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 15'+path+'.mp4'
log_path = r'C:\log.txt'
os.system(t + ' >> ' + log_path + ' 2>&1')
```

Probably, cause of such issue is lack of spaces between ffmpeg parameters (such as -f / -i).

Comment: Yes - might be worth a quick `print t` line just to check what command is actually going to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output and print it from Python itself. Say:

```
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT

try:
    output = check_output(t, shell=True, stderr=STDOUT)
except CalledProcessError, e:
    output = e.output
```

`check_output` will raise an exception if the command returns with status code != 0. I'm capturing the error output in there too, just in case.

Comment: Then you can just `print (output)`, for example.